# Infinite HTTP 301 redirect loop inside Symfony 3.4 application when creating a new blank slash (/) route

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-301, symfony-3.4

I am having a hard time understanding why I am hitting an infinite HTTP 301 redirect loop inside my Symfony 3.4.20 application when I build a route like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/temp-crmpicco")
 */
class TempController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     "/",
     *     name="temp_crmpicco_index"
     * )
     *
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('@App/CRMPicco/index.html.twig', []);
    }
}
```

However, when I define the route as the following it works.

```
 * @Route( 
 *     "/crm",
 *     name="temp_crmpicco_index"
 * )
```

The redirects look like this in the console:

[image: infinite http 301 redirect loop]

```
$ bin/console --env=dev debug:route | grep crmpicco
  temp_crmpicco_index                                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/temp-crmpicco/
```

Why does the route only work when I give it a random value? Surely it can be just /.

Comment: Maybe there are other action with empty route?. Look this https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#routing-trailing-slash-redirection

Comment: @Ali Hi, thanks for the comment. It's not empty though. The route is defined as `/temp-crmpicco/` and there's no other route defined like that.

Comment: I have noticed that there is a difference in size between the request with slash and without slash 1.10Kb vs. 0.99Kb, maybe a redirection is being by the server (htaccess for example) and another by the synfony?.